# How to “pad” a variable-length string with a string?

Tags: perl

Say I have a variable `$foo` that has a length between 1 and 10.

And there is a variable `$bar` with a length of 12 that is initially set to `Iamheretopad`.

I want to overwrite the second variable **right-justified** with the first one.

A few examples:

```
$foo    $bar
1       Iamheretopa1
123     Iamhereto123
123456  Iamher123456
```

Comment: We prefer that those who ask questions show some effort at actually solving the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $bar is 12 characters long and $foo is 5 characters long, then you want the first 7 characters of $bar, 7 being the difference of the lengths (12-5).

```
$bar = substr($bar, 0, length($bar)-length($foo)) . $foo;
```

Alternatively, if $foo is 5 characters long, you could replace the last 5 characters of $bar.

```
substr($bar, -length($foo)) = $foo;
```

By the way, if you wanted to pad with spaces or zeroes, you can use `sprintf`.

```
$bar = sprintf('%12s', $foo);         # Spaces, constant size
$bar = sprintf('%*s', $size, $foo);   # Spaces, variable size
$bar = sprintf('%012s', $foo);        # Zeroes, constant size
$bar = sprintf('%0*s', $size, $foo);  # Zeroes, variable size
```